# can I use shared dataset as available values for parameters?

Tags: reporting-services

I have multiple report that has same parameters so I made share dataset I want to make
these parameters available values from query which is the `shared dataset` I made before
but I am not able to choose that share dataset from list item of values from query I only see the none shared dataset ... so

How I can use shared dataset for building parameter values from shared dataset ??

Comment: The shared dataset has to be added to each report before it can be used. Other than that you should be able to use the shared dataset just like any other dataset in the report. I do this all the time for, as an example, a Geography parameter which gets used in most of my reports.